# How to integrate fbml with html and php?

Tags: php, html, fbml

I want to make a form that require some jquery, javascript and a few css stylesheet. And I also want to add an autocomplete of fb friend list, something like fbml fb:friend-selector

After a long search, I found that fbml cannot run if I have html, body, and style tag..
Is it right? Or I can do that with another way?
thanks

Comment: Does this app run on Facebook or your website?   If it's a Facebook page or canvas tab Use an iframe app and you can put any code you want into it.

Comment: this app run on Facebook..
iframe? so, I put the fbml in an iframe? I've tried it but it seem doesn't work..
btw, thanks for your comment, I'll try it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

My dear who said you that fbml cannot run if you are having html etc.? you just need to add `xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"` in your `<html>` tag and then you can use fbml and all facebook related stuff in your web page despite of the fact that whatever you are having on that page. After inserting that your `<html>` tag should look like

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en">
```

Comment: I've already do that..
but, still doesn't work...
now, I try to make my friend-selector with jquery..
I'll try the fbml later, because I must submit my work a few days later...
anyway, thanks very much for your reply.. I'll try it as soon as possible.. :)

Comment: @Bobby Stenly what kind of problem you are facing? is there any error?

Comment: I tried to use the fbml in my form that I build with PHP and HTML. but, when I put the fbml code like fb:friend-selector, it didn't work. No error message and nothing happened.. >,<

Comment: @Bobby Stenly are you connecting with facebook. Means how you are connecting facebook using JS SDK? Are you connecting synchorounously or asynchorously?

Comment: Sorry, it's took a long time to reply your comment..
I tried Facebook PHP SDK..
mmmm
I don't know what the synchronously connection or Asyn connection... I just took a look at Facebook apps and try to understand how it's worked..